# Prime factorization and hcf

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, prime-factorization, gcd-and-lcm

For any given integer $n$, we prime factorize it as follows
 $$n = p_1^{k_1} \cdot p_2^{k_2} \cdots p_r^{k_r}. $$

Let $g = \gcd(k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_r)$ and $m_i = k_i / g$.

The function $F$ is defined as: $$F(n) = p_1^{m_1} · p_2^{m_2} \cdots p_r^{m_r}.$$
I need the value of $F(2) + F(3) + \cdots + F(n)$. How shall I proceed?
Example:
 $1936 = 2^4.11^2$
g = hcf(4, 2) = 2
$F(1936) = 2^{4/2}.11^{2/2}$
$F(1936) = 2^{2}.11^{1}$
$F(1936) = 44$

Comment: What is $m_i$ you mentioned in the second line?

Comment: $m_i$ is the new power of each prime. It is the original power upon the hcf of all prime powers that the original number comprised of.

Comment: Basically, $F(n)$ is the smallest integer $k$ such that $n=k^a$ for some integer $a$.

Comment: Notice the proper way to code $g=\gcd(k_1,k_,\ldots,k_r)$, as in my edit to the question. (I also dealt with some other MathJax newbieisms. $\qquad$

Comment: @wythagoras $\alpha$ is not some integer but the largest integer for which $n = k^{\alpha}$is true.

Comment: @maverick True. That is already implied by the fact that $k$ is the smallest such integer.

Comment: @wythagoras True.

Comment: @wythagoras I found this paper, but couldn't understand it. Please have a look. http://cr.yp.to/lineartime/powers2-20060914-ams.pdf and the other is
http://cr.yp.to/papers/powers.pdf

Comment: The numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A067440 and a Maple program is given, but no "pattern" is found (and I don't know why you would expect there would be one).

Comment: @GerryMyerson The list is till 51 only. I need answer for 10^500. If not pattern, then what can I expect? :/

Comment: May I ask why you need an answer for $10^{500}$? Anyway, you can add up all the numbers up to $n$, subtract the appropriate numbers for the squares, cubes, fifth powers, and so on, put bacl in the appropriate numbers for the sixth, tenth, 14th powers, and so on, and so on, by Inclusion-Exclusion.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can you be more clear? I could not understand you.

Comment: Can you answer my question first?

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's the constraint I am dealing with.

Comment: Sorry, that's not an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I didn't get you sir. That was a constraint I was given to accomodate in the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35721/discussion-between-maverick-and-gerry-myerson).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat. Who gave you the constraint? Where does the problem come from? Why does ANYONE need an answer for $10^{500}$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is unresponsive to repeated questions.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I converged to the following results.
$F(n)$ is the **smallest number** $k$, that can be raised to some power to $\alpha$.
$$F(n) = k^{\alpha}, $$ where k is as small as possible.
Now 1 <= $\alpha$ <= $log_2$(n). So we iterate for different values of $\alpha$, and check whether $n^{1/\alpha}$ is integer or not.
This gives us the value of $F(n)$, but I am not able to find the pattern in
 $F(2) + F(3) + ... + F(n).$